# Is there any case when the userAccountControl attribute is blank?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I'm trying to find out why some of users in my AD on Windows 2008 Server R2 don't have the 'userAccountControl' attribute and there is no way to fetch any information about them. As far as I know this attribute is mandatory for all users, but I cannot find documentation on this. MSDN say nothing about this. What doesn't it mean that the attribute is not existed? Does it mean that the user has been improperly created?

Comment: Does `repadmin /showobjmeta dcName "DN of user account"` show a userAccountControl attribute?

Comment: Yes, it does. What I tried is fetching this attribute using ldp.exe. It didn't work until I ran this util with administrative privileges. See comment to Ryan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `userAccountControl` will always have a value even if it's zero.

Your issue might be that the user making the query doesn't have permission to read the attribute for some reason. That would be strange if you haven't changed permissions in AD from the defaults. It's also easy to test by using a Domain Admin account to do the query.

It may also be that however you are querying the attributes isn't returning the `userAccountControl` attribute in the response data. Most LDAP client implementations will let you specify which attributes you want returned in the response data and `userAccountControl` isn't in the default set. So you typically have to request it explicitly.

Comment: Yes, look like you are right regarding lacking of permissions in AD. I just tried to launch ldp.exe as Administrator and it show me userAccountControl attribute. The next question comes from here - where I can take a look at and change those permissions which are responsible for that?

Comment: Any of the GUI tools that let you view properties of AD objects should have a Security tab in the properties dialog.  From there, use the Advanced button to see the complete list of access rules on the object.